How to Iterate Over a Dictionary of DataFrames Based on String Values
I have an Excel file with three sheets, each sharing the same structure but containing different data.

Initially, I successfully wrote 'success' in all rows of the 'Dummy' column where the STUDENT NAME was either 'Roberto' or 'Leonardo'.
Now, I want to write 'failure' in the same column, in every sheet, where a different 'STUDENT NAME' is present.
So far, I have tried with ELSE but it is not working as expected.
Below are snapshots of each sheet in my Excel file, along with the parsed original OrderedDict, for clarity.

My original OrderedDict:
{'Sheet_1':     ID      Name  Surname  Grade favourite color    favourite sport  Dummy
 0  104  Eleanor     Rigby      6            blue  American football    NaN
 1  168  Barbara       Ann      8            pink             Hockey    NaN
 2  450    Polly   Cracker      7           black      Skateboarding    NaN
 3   90   Little      Josy     10          orange            Cycling    NaN,
 'Sheet_2':     ID       Name   Surname  Grade favourite color favourite sport  Dummy
 0  106       Lucy       Sky      8          yellow          Tennis    NaN
 1  128    Delilah     Perez      5     light green      Basketball    NaN
 2  100  Christina   Rodwell      3           black       Badminton    NaN
 3   40      Ziggy  Stardust      7             red          Squash    NaN,
 'Sheet_3':     ID   Name   Surname  Grade favourite color favourite sport  Dummy
 0   22   Lucy  Diamonds      9           brown            Judo    NaN
 1   50  Grace     Kelly      7           white       Taekwondo    NaN
 2  105    Uma   Thurman      7          purple      videogames    NaN
 3   29   Lola   McQueen      3             red            Surf    NaN}

My piece of code (not writing 'failure' for 'Miquel Angelo'):
# Importing modules
import openpyxl as op
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import xlsxwriter
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook


# Defining the file path
file_path = r'C:/Users/machukovich/Desktop/stack_2.xlsx'

# Load workbook as openpyxl
reference_workbook = load_workbook(file_path)

# We will mantain the workbook open
wb = reference_workbook.active

# Getting the sheetnames as a list using the sheetnames attribute

sheet_names = reference_workbook.sheetnames
print(sheet_names)

names_list = []
for sheet in reference_workbook.worksheets:
    student_name = sheet['B2'].value
    names_list.append(student_name)
    print(f"Student Name: {student_name}")
    
    
print(f"List of Names: {names_list}")

# Loading the file into a dictionary of Dataframes
dict_of_df = pd.read_excel(file_path, sheet_name=None, skiprows=2)

# Writing the loop itself (it fills all the 'Dummy' columns with zeros in all sheets):
for sheet_name, df in dict_of_df.items():
    if student_name =='Roberto' or  student_name =='Leonardo':
        df['Dummy'] = df['Dummy'].fillna('success')
    else:
        df['Dummy'] = df['Dummy'].fillna('failure')

Snapshots:




'student_name' is derived from the name lookup in cell 'B2'. The last value for 'student_name' is 'Leonardo' and this is never changed later. Then in the line of code if student_name =='Roberto' or  student_name =='Leonardo': the 'if' criteria check on 'Leonardo' is True. Logically True OR anything else is always True so that line is always going to be True, the 'else' part of the criteria will never be used. Do you want to loop through names from row 4 to 7 in column B and set only the corresponding cell in column G to success/failure dependent on matching the name in B2? or something else?

@moken I don't want to loop through names from row 4 to 7 in column B. I need to loop through the cell B2 in all sheets, If B2 = 'Miquel Angelo' , as in the second sheet, I need to fulfill the 'Dummy' column with the string 'failure'. Better said.. if B2 is different from 'Leonardo' or 'Roberto'  the 'Dummy' column has to be fulfilled with the string 'failure'.

I have erased the part in which the list for B2 values was generated.
For more clarity.
Here is the solution I was looking for:
# Importing modules
import pandas as pd
from openpyxl import load_workbook

# Defining the file path
file_path = r'C:/Users/machukovich/Desktop/stack_2.xlsx'

# Load workbook as openpyxl
reference_workbook = load_workbook(file_path)

# Loading the file into a dictionary of DataFrames
dict_of_df = pd.read_excel(file_path, sheet_name=None, skiprows=2)

# Iterating through each sheet and filling the 'Dummy' column based on student names
for sheet_name, df in dict_of_df.items():
    student_name = reference_workbook[sheet_name]['B2'].value
    df['Dummy'] = 'success' if student_name in ['Roberto', 'Leonardo'] else 'failure'

Thank you all who have tried to help me.

I think what you are missing is what moken mentioned in the first comment. The value of student_name is last read from sheet 3 and has the value Leonardo. Though the value of student_name is added to the names_list, that list is unused. Hence the value of student_name remains as Leonardo in the line if student_name =='Roberto' or  student_name =='Leonardo': when you iterate through each of the sheets and hence it'll only write success into the Dummy column. Maybe you meant to use values from the names_list while iterating through the sheets? Something like the below works as expected for me and writes failure for the second sheet:
        index = 0
        for sheet_name, df in dict_of_df.items():
            student_name = names_list[index]
            index += 1
            print(f"Student Name in loop: {student_name}")

            if student_name =='Roberto' or  student_name =='Leonardo':
                df['Dummy'] = df['Dummy'].fillna('success')
            else:
                df['Dummy'] = df['Dummy'].fillna('failure')
            df[['Dummy']].apply(print)

Complete log output:
[2024-04-20, 22:31:09 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:151} INFO - ['Sheet_1', 'Sheet_2', 'Sheet_3']
[2024-04-20, 22:31:09 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:151} INFO - Student Name: Roberto
[2024-04-20, 22:31:09 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:151} INFO - Student Name: Miquel Angelo
[2024-04-20, 22:31:09 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:151} INFO - Student Name: Leonardo
[2024-04-20, 22:31:09 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:151} INFO - List of Names: ['Roberto', 'Miquel Angelo', 'Leonardo']
[2024-04-20, 22:31:09 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:151} INFO - Student Name in loop: Roberto
[2024-04-20, 22:31:09 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:151} INFO - 0    success
1    success
2    success
3    success
Name: Dummy, dtype: object
[2024-04-20, 22:31:09 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:151} INFO - Student Name in loop: Miquel Angelo
[2024-04-20, 22:31:09 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:151} INFO - 0    failure
1    failure
2    failure
3    failure
Name: Dummy, dtype: object
[2024-04-20, 22:31:09 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:151} INFO - Student Name in loop: Leonardo
[2024-04-20, 22:31:09 UTC] {logging_mixin.py:151} INFO - 0    success
1    success
2    success
3    success
Name: Dummy, dtype: object


Very much appreciated your answer. But it is not fully what I was looking for. It might be that my question wasn't clear enough.
